# search in PHP Array, similar to MySQL Like %var% search with livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I saw other questions that usually use `preg_grep` but my problem was not solved
In the LiveWire component, I receive information from the web service and display it in a table.
Now the user does the search and I want to display the items that look like the searched phrase

I wrote the code like this:

```
class Cryptolist extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public bool $loadData = false;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    public $perPage = 10;
    public $search = '';

    public function init()
    {
        $this->loadData = true;
    }

    public function getBalance($asset)
    {
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('setPrice' ,[
                'asset' => $asset,
                'price' => getCryptoBalance($asset)
            ]);
    }
    

    public function setPerPage(int $page)
    {
        $this->perPage = $page;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        try {
            if ($this->loadData == true) {
                $api = new \Binance\API('','');
                $coins = $api->coins();
            } else {
                $coins = [];
            }
            return view('livewire.backend.crypto.cryptolist')->with('coins' , collect(preg_grep('~'.$this->search.'~i', $coins))->paginate($this->perPage));
        }catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            return view('wrong')->with('e' , $e);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is view:

```
<div class="nk-block" id="loadesh1" >
    <div class="card card-bordered card-stretch">
        <div class="card-inner-group">
            <div class="card-inner position-relative card-tools-toggle">
                <div class="card-title-group">
                    <div class="card-tools mr-n1">
                        <ul class="btn-toolbar gx-1">
                            <li>
                                <a class="btn btn-icon search-toggle toggle-search" data-target="search" href="#"><em class="icon ni ni-search"></em></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="btn-toolbar-sep"></li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="toggle-wrap">
                                    <a class="btn btn-icon btn-trigger toggle" data-target="cardTools" href="#"><em class="icon ni ni-menu-right"></em></a>
                                    <div class="toggle-content" data-content="cardTools">
                                        <ul class="btn-toolbar gx-1">
                                            <li class="toggle-close">
                                                <a class="btn btn-icon btn-trigger toggle" data-target="cardTools" href="#"><em class="icon ni ni-arrow-left"></em></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="dropdown">
                                                    <a class="btn btn-trigger btn-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><em class="icon ni ni-setting"></em></a>
                                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-xs dropdown-menu-right">
                                                        <ul class="link-check">
                                                            <li><span>show</span></li>
                                                            <li @if($perPage === 10) class="active" @endif>
                                                                <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="setPerPage(10)">10</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li @if($perPage === 20) class="active" @endif>
                                                                <a href="#"wire:click.prevent="setPerPage(20)">20</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li @if($perPage === 50) class="active" @endif>
                                                                <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="setPerPage(50)">50</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-search search-wrap" data-search="search">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="search-content">
                            <a class="search-back btn btn-icon toggle-search" data-target="search" href="#"><em class="icon ni ni-arrow-left"></em></a><input wire:model="search" class="form-control border-transparent form-focus-none" placeholder="type for search" type="text"><button class="search-submit btn btn-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-search"></em></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-inner p-0" wire:init="init">
                <div class="nk-tb-list nk-tb-ulist">
                    <div class="nk-tb-item nk-tb-head">
                        <div class="nk-tb-col">
                            <span class="sub-text">name</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb">
                            <span class="sub-text">balance</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @foreach ($coins as $item => $value)
                        <div class="nk-tb-item">
                            <div class="nk-tb-col">
                                <a href="/demo5/user-details-regular.html">
                                    <div class="user-card">
                                        <div class="user-avatar d-none d-sm-flex">

                                            @if(file_exists(public_path() . '/img/crypto/'.strtolower($value['coin'].".svg")))
                                                <img style="border-radius: 0" src="{{asset('/img/crypto/'.strtolower($value['coin']))}}.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                            @else
                                                <img style="border-radius: 0" src="https://demo.rayanscript.ir/-/vendor/cryptocurrency-icons/32/color/noimage.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                            @endif

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="user-info">
                                            <span class="tb-lead english" style="font-weight: bolder">{{$value['name']}}</span>
                                            <span class="english">{{$value['coin']}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb">
                                <div class="btn-group" aria-label="Basic example">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-dim btn-light" wire:click="getBalance('{{$value['coin']}}')">
                                        <div wire:loading wire:target="getBalance('{{$value['coin']}}')">
                                            <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="w-120px" id="coin-{{$value['coin']}}">get balance</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-dim btn-primary">add coin</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this error is given. Is my search method correct?

```
Array to string conversion
```

Comment: what do you want from this code " collect(preg_grep('~'.$this->search.'~i', $coins) "

Comment: There is an input on the page where the user enters the search text. And `$ this-> search` is the user text for the search that is stored in this variable. I want to show the items that are in the `coins` array and are similar to the user search text @GauravGupta

Comment: remove collect and paginate and try again data only

Comment: again error `Array to string conversion` returned. @GauravGupta

Comment: why are using encode and decode when it's already in array? your error must be at encode line try by using dd after encode and the before

Comment: It makes no difference, I also deleted them, but again this error is given.
Do you think my method of doing the search is correct? @GauravGupta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235691/discussion-between-gaurav-gupta-and-awminux).